# iKanoo speaker not working

Tags: sound, speakers

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Win 10. I am using a USB speaker (iKanoo its name) and it is working fine with Win. It was also working fine with Ubuntu, but it seems to not be functioning anymore. I can see that the speaker is detected by the system, but it does not produce any sound. Sometimes I can also see the bar in the settings is moving when a sound is playing, but not always. The internal audio works fine as well, it is just the USB speaker that is not working. lspci -v shows two audio devices and I moved the speaker to another USB port and it is not working there either.

Any ideas/help?

Comment: Just bought one these off of Amazon. It worked the first time I plugged it in to my Elementary OS Hera 5.x system with is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. If you look at dmesg output in the pastebin below you can see that the speaker is being detected as a USB storage device. It still shows up in my sound control panel with both analog and digital devices, but no sound will come out of it.
https://pastebin.com/kkWsjGxg

Comment: Found some more diagnostic output using lsinput 
/dev/input/event11
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0xe2b7
   product : 0x811
   version : 513
   name    : "CD002 CD002"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input3"
   uniq    : "CD002"
and udevadm monitor command https://pastebin.com/95biG82a

Comment: Here is the Jie Li device https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/E2B7/device/0811

Comment: The product mfg and model is the iKanoo N12. This is the link the the Amazon page. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07G7TNJH7  Web site for www.ikanoo.com appears defunct, it redirects to a hosting payment page.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my speaker bar working on the latest beta of Elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Which build are you running?

Dmesg output shows that it's still trying to detect and mount a USB mass storage device when the speaker is plugged in, but I imagine this is some vestigial functionality that is embedded in the chipset the device was built with.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Linux MINT 20.2 which is Ubuntu-based.

In the config file /etc/modprobe.d/alsabase.conf comment out the line
`options snd-usb-audio index=-2`.

```bsh
#options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Then either restart or give the terminal command:

```bsh
sudo alsa force-reload
```

See the site:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices
but not all the directions that are given there were necessary for me.

Comment: What do you mean ‘not all the directions there were necessary for me’? Please give a bit more detail, thank you!

Comment: LM is not Ubuntu, so it is off topic here. I suggest you make sure the answer works on Ubuntu, and then post.